# execute a javascript code when item selected from drop list

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I want to execute a java script code when item selected from the drop list "jumpMenu"

javascript code:

```
function MM_jumpMenu(selObj){ 

switch(selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value)
{

    case 2:
      document.getElementById("method2").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("method3").style.display = 'block';
      break;
    case 3:
      document.getElementById("method3").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("method2").style.display = 'block';
      break;


   }
}
```

java script will affect this html code:

```
<div id="method2"></div>
<div id="method3"></div>
```

drop list:

```
<select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu" onchange="MM_jumpMenu(this)">
            <option value="1">item1</option>
            <option value="2">item2</option>
            <option value="3">item3</option>
</select>
```

**update** i should have used quotes **""** with *the switch cases*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you are looking for is called `selectedIndex`.

```
 selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value
```